# Get HttpWebResponse from Html Agility Pack HtmlWeb

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, httpwebresponse

Can `HttpWebResponse` be obtained from Html Agility Pack `HtmlWeb`?

As in, if I call:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb ();
HtmlDocument document = web.Load ("http://stackoverflow.com/");
```

Is there a convenient method to retrieve the `HttpWebResponse` from the `web` instance to view headers - such as to retrieve header properties like content type?

There are pre and post delegates, which will work:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb ();

web.PreRequest = delegate (HttpWebRequest request) {
    request.Timeout = 10 * 1000;
    return true;
};
web.PostResponse = delegate (HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response) {
    //response.Headers;
    //response.ContentType;
};

HtmlDocument document = web.Load ("http://stackoverflow.com/");
```

Instead, is there a way to get the response something like: `(HttpWebResponse)web.GetResponse();`

Comment: Why not just make the request yourself and hand the string that you extract from the response to HAP? HtmlDocument.LoadHtml is your friend here.

Comment: Thanks - that makes the most sense.  I'll accept that.

Comment: Hmm... it's not quite so straightforward because the detection of charset used in HTML is a thorny business. I've done this before... looking for the code.

Comment: I'd go with @LB's answer, but for future reference, when downloading string content, WebClient.DownloadString and DownloadStringAsync runs a whole bag of tricks to detect encoding from the content-type header's `charset=...` suffix and byte order marks. Can be handy if you're fetching from diverse sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `TaskCompletionSource` + async/await

```
var web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpWebResponse>();

web.PostResponse = delegate(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response)
{
    tcs.SetResult(response);
};

var  document = web.Load("http://stackoverflow.com/");
var httpWebResponse = await tcs.Task;
```